# Creating a loop in JS for a web application

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to loop this function at least ten times but can't seem to get it to work on my web application.

I am learning JS at school and this is as far as i've come

```
$(function fade_in_pictures() {
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    $('.wi2').delay(2000).fadeIn(0);
    $('.wi1').delay(2000).fadeOut(0);
    $('.wi1').delay(4000).fadeIn(0);
    $('.wi2').delay(4000).fadeOut(0);
    $('.wi2').delay(2000).fadeIn(0);
    $('.wi1').delay(2000).fadeOut(0);
  }
});
```

ERROR:Parsing error: Unexcepted Token i

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have type-specific declarations – `int i`. It uses generalized keywords – `var`, `let`, and `const`.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski I believe your comment should be the answer to this question!